# Discord.js event random avatar

Tags: discord.js, command

i'm trying to make a system. I want the members on the server to randomly select and send every minutes the "jpeg/png" photos in their profile to the specified channel. something like a "png-archive". I do not know how to do it.can u help ?

Answer (score 0):

You can run this inside of an infinite loop (search on internet how to setup it) :

```
let avatarEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(colorcode)
        .setAuthor(member.username)
        .setImage(member.displayAvatarURL());
channel.send(avatarEmbed);
```

Replace `colorcode` by a color of your choice, `member` by the member you want the bot to display the profile picture (if you want all the members to be selected you can get the Collection of all members then run this inside of a foreach loop) and `channel` by the channel object.